# Javascript events wont work anymore when i changed the body tag classes in my html?

Tags: javascript, html, css

i'm building a website portfolio with an interactive display at the top with some click events and hover. However i changed the 'body' class so i could fit it in with my website and then the javascript stopped working and i can't for the life of me figure it out?!

(sorry if i didnt show enough snippets..) I'm using scss but i used a transpiler to convert it into css when i switched it over to VSC..

the normal javscript like time and date work fine - it just seems to be the elements connected on the page / in the now 'display' div which i cant connect to anymore..

It works fine when the classes are with body  - code:

```css
html, body {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

body {
  background: #CCBBFF;
  z-index: -10;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.mainDisp {
  width: 1000px;
  height: 550px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  // overflow: hidden;
}


html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}
* {
  position: absolute;
}
*:before,
*:after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
}


.lamp {
  width: 120px;
  height: 80px;
  background: #494949;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0 48%, 100% 48%);
clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0 48%, 100% 48%);
  left: 45%;
  top: 10%;
  z-index: 4;
}
```

```html
</head>

<body>

  
<div class="mainDisp">
  <div class="lamp"></div>
  <div class="innerLight hidden"></div>
  <div class="string"></div>
  
  ....
```

but when i add a new class 'Display' and add the old body's classes the javascript just doesnt work anymore? Same Javascript for both..

code :

```js
function openURL(url) {
  window.open(url);
}

var book1 = document.querySelector('.book');
var super1 = document.querySelector('.super1');
var book2 = document.querySelector('.book.two');
var super2 = document.querySelector('.super2');
var book3 = document.querySelector('.book.three');
var super3 = document.querySelector('.super3');
var calculator = document.querySelector('.calculator');
var calc = document.querySelector('.calc');
var phone = document.querySelector('.phone');
var tipCalc = document.querySelector('.tipCalc');
var lightSwitch = document.querySelector('.switch');
var lamp = document.querySelector('.innerLight');

lightSwitch.addEventListener('click', function() {
  lamp.classList.toggle('hidden');
})

book1.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  super1.classList.remove('hidden')
});

book1.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  super1.classList.add('hidden')
});

book2.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  super2.classList.remove('hidden')
});

book2.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  super2.classList.add('hidden')
});

book3.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  super3.classList.remove('hidden')
});

book3.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  super3.classList.add('hidden')
});

calculator.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  calc.classList.remove('hidden')
});

calculator.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  calc.classList.add('hidden')
});

phone.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
  tipCalc.classList.remove('hidden')
});

phone.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
  tipCalc.classList.add('hidden')
});


// CALENDAR DATE

const dayDisp = document.querySelector('#day');
const monthDisp = document.querySelector('#month');

var months = ['Jan','Feb','Mar','Apr','May','June','July','Aug','Sept','Oct','Nov','Dec'];

var now = new Date();
var date = now.getDate();
var month = months[now.getMonth()];

dayDisp.innerText = date;
monthDisp.innerText = month;


// MAIN CLOCK //

var hourHand = document.querySelector('.hour');
var minHand = document.querySelector('.min');
var secHand = document.querySelector('.sec');

function setDate() {
    const now = new Date;
    const secs = now.getSeconds();
    const secondDegrees = ((secs / 60) * 360) + 90;
    secHand.style.transform = `rotate(${secondDegrees}deg)`;


    const mins = now.getMinutes();
    const minsDegrees = ((mins / 60) * 360) + 90;
    minHand.style.transform = `rotate(${minsDegrees}deg)`;
  
    const hours = now.getHours();
    const hourDegrees = ((hours / 12) * 360) + 90;
    hourHand.style.transform = `rotate(${hourDegrees}deg)`;
  
}

setInterval(setDate, 1000);
```

```css
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
}

body {
    background: #fdf5e6;  
}

html {
    box-sizing: border-box;
}


-----------


.display {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #CCBBFF;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: -10;

    * {
        position: absolute;
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    *:before, *:after {
        position: absolute;
        content: '';
        box-sizing: inherit;
    }

    .mainDisp {
        position: absolute;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 550px;
        // border: 1px solid black;
        z-index: -10;
        box-sizing: inherit;
    

        .lamp {
            position: absolute;
            width: 120px;
            height: 80px;
            background: #494949;
            -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0 48%, 100% 48%);
        clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0 48%, 100% 48%);
            left: 45%;
            top: 10%;
            z-index: 4;
        }
        
        .innerLight {
            position: absolute;
            z-index: 1;
            width: 100%;
            height: 900px;
            -webkit-clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0 48%, 100% 48%);
            clip-path: polygon(50% 0%, 0 48%, 100% 48%);
            background: rgba(253,245,230, 0.4);
            left: 1%;
            top: 55px;
        }
```

```html
</head>
  <body>

    <div class="container">
        <header>
            <div class="intro">
                <h1 class="name">NAME</h1>
            </div>
            <nav>
                <li><a href="#about">About</a></li>
                <li><a href="#projects">Projects</a></li>
                <li><a href="#skills">Skills</a></li>
                <li><a href="#contact">Contact</a></li>
            </nav>
        </header>
    
        <div class='display'>
            <div class="mainDisp">
                    <div class="lamp"></div>
                    <div class="innerLight hidden"></div>
                    <div class="string"></div>
                    <div class="super1 hidden"></div>
                    <div class="super2 hidden"></div>
                    <div class="super3 hidden"></div>
                    <!-- <div class="window" onclick="openURL('https://codepen.io/Eejay/full/VQBvOm/')" target="_blank"> -->
                    <div class='windows'>
                        <div class="outside">
                            <div class="moon"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div class="inner"></div>
                        <div class="inner two"></div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="ledge"></div>
                    <div class="mainClock">
                        <div class="hour"></div>
                        <div class="min"></div>
                        <div class="sec"></div>
                    </div>
```

Any help appreciated! I know its probably something really simple but i can't put my finger on it....

Comment: Your code could really benefit from data attributes so you are not copy and pasting the same code over and over.

Comment: `the javascript just doesnt work anymore` please be specific, what doesn't work? Also it would be nice to recreate the problem and not just copy/paste your code as is.

Comment: So click on the error in the console ``"message": "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null",``, it takes you to a line 141 `lightSwitch.addEventListener(`, and that class does not exist that you are search for. This is assuming you provided all the code.... If not, provide it...

Comment: your code snippets are not enough to reproduce your issue.

Comment: .display .mainDisp not closed }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Problem is that you set your `z-index` of .display to `-10`. Its not clickable anymore.

Setting it to `0` will fix your issue:

```
.display {
     width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    background: #CCBBFF;
    position: relative;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    z-index: 0;
}
```

take a look at this forked [codepen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/qLZBYL).

Comment: amazing!!! i knew i was doing something silly - thank you so much!! It works perfectly :)